# how to create a T- flip flop in ladder logic?

Tags: plc, digital-logic, flip-flop

This is a bridge application where I need to alternate between 2 motors. Therefore, if you use motor 1 in the first raise/lower bridge cycle, you need to use motor 2 for the second bridge cycle. When the bridge is fully seated, there is a digital signal that is sent which needs to be used to toggle between the 2 motors. I know a T-flip flop can be used because you only need one input. I just need to know if this can be implemented in ladder logic.

Thanks!

DJ

Answer (score 1):

Sure... Just have to use a bonus coil to get your edge triggered value on the invert, and be careful of execution order, this should be functionally equivalent to a T flip flop though, biased towards Q on first scan.

[image: T Flip Flop Ladder Implementation]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Depending on how you want to use it you may or may not require the independent Q and Q' coils, you can possibly just get away with tapping a single coil and using inverts as required.
Additionally, if you already have command clearing logic that can be used to guarantee that T is a single scan coil from your Scada then you won't need the T' coil.
If "T" is a field pushbutton then you are going to want the edge transitional anyway to account for PB failures